# How do I pass a parameter from my Jenkins dsl pipelineJob to a bash script?

Tags: bash, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I have a Jenkins job dsl pipeline which calls a groovy script.

My groovy script then runs a number of jobs, each of which calls a bash script to do the actual testing.

I want to be able to set a variable in the pipeline at run time from the jenkins UI (when building w/ parameters) and have that parameter accessible from my bash scripts.

Is this possible using a job dsl pipeline?

Comment: You could consider using the [envinject plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/envinject/)

Comment: if your groovy script is calling jenkins job, you can have it pass as parameters to those jobs.

Answer (score 0):

### Without plugins

- invoke the child job using parameters [...]
- inside the child job receive the param and inject it as environment variable
- inside of bash script read it as environment variable

**Parent job**

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('parent_job') {
            steps {
                script {
                    env.GLOBAL_VARIABLE = "foo"
                    build job: "call_child_bash", wait: true, parameters: [string(name: 'parent_variable', value: "foo")]
                }                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Child job**

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('child_bash') {
            steps {
                script {
                    env.GLOBAL_VARIABLE = params.parent_variable
                    sh "/tmp/sandbox/child_bash.sh"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

**Child bash: /tmp/sandbox/child_bash.sh**

```
echo "the global GLOBAL_VARIABLE value is $GLOBAL_VARIABLE"
```

**Parent job result**

[image]

**Child job result**

[image]